# How to use fswatch and rsync to automatically sync directories?

Tags: macos, rsync, fswatch

I'd like to automatically run a one way sync between two local directories using `rsync`. Meaning when a change is detected in a file of `/dir1` or its subdirs, the following command should run:

`rsync -rtuv /dir1 /dir2`

How can I go about achieving this with `fswatch`?

Is it possible to supply arguments for `rsync` to only copy the actual files that were changed, as given by the `fswatch` events?

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: `rsync` is already pretty optimal about only doing the minimum necessary updates - why not just go with `fswatch . | while read f; do echo rsync; done` ?  http://bryanpendleton.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/rsync-algorithm.html

Answer (score 40):

```
alias run_rsync='rsync -azP --exclude ".*/" --exclude ".*" --exclude "tmp/" ~/Documents/repos/my_repository username@host:~'
run_rsync; fswatch -o . | while read f; do run_rsync; done
```

Second line runs `run_rsync` once unconditionally and then - on each change in current directory (or specify exact path instead of `.`)

Rsync options:

- -a - stands for "archive" and syncs recursively and preserves symbolic links, special and device files, modification times, group, owner, and permissions.
- -z - compression
- -P - combines the flags --progress and --partial. The first of these gives you a progress bar for the transfers and the second allows you to resume interrupted transfers
- --exclude - excludes files by pattern

You will need `fswatch`:

```
brew install fswatch
```

Comment: Very nice ninja post. Perhaps using `-or` after `fswatch` would be better, for recursiveness.

Comment: Beware: fswatch scans entire tree even if you exclude things. https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/issues/151. That is, your `node_modules` if you have one will be completely scanned.

Comment: Wouldn't this call rsync for every changed file, while it only needs to be called ones since rsync also checks what files have changed?

Comment: No, the -o option means --one-per-batch. See here: https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/wiki/How-to-Use-fswatch#bubbling-events.

Comment: @vaughan Oops that is huge. Is there any workarounds?

Comment: Note that the file being watched is the current dir in the example: Replace the . in `fswarch -o .` by the dir to be watched. (probably equal to source dir)

Answer (score 2):

For a one-line solution:

```
function run_rsync() { rsync your_args } ; run_rsync; fswatch -o your_directory | while read f; do run_rsync; done
```

Thanks @Daniel for the inspiring answer.